# Write multi dimensional dictionary to file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary

I have a code that calculates several metrics which are stored as a 3 dimensional dictrionary of dictionaries. I would like to print this dictionary to a csv file - but haven't found a good approach in doing so.

Once all elements within the dictionary are calculated, I would like to print it to file (where the different `periods` are the headers of the file and the `keys` and the metrics `a, b, and c` should be columns - column keys and column metrics).

Is there an easy way to print this to file? (my first attempt was pandas but this did not work)

Thanks

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import os
import random


# 3 dimensional dictionary that stores integers 
output_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
# Array of periods
periods = range(0, 2)
# relevant keys
keys = ["key1", "key2"]

# Iterate over all periods
for period in periods:
    # Iterate over all relevant keys
    for key in keys:

        # Store results for key for each time period for each category ("a", "b", or "c")
        output_dict[key][period]["a"] += random.randint(1, 1000)
        output_dict[key][period]["b"] += random.randint(1, 1000)
        output_dict[key][period]["c"] += random.randint(1, 1000)

# This is the tricky part!!!
# Store results 
pd.DataFrame(output_dict).to_csv("output_dict.csv", index=False)

# the dictionary may look as follows:
output_dict = {"key1": {0: {"a": 0.9, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.5}, 1:{"a": 0.91, "b": 0.3, "c": 0.4}},
               "key2": {0: {"a": 0.4, "b": 0.33, "c": 0.34}, 1: {"a": 0.21, "b": 0.73, "c": 0.54}}}
```

[image]

Comment: First, try transforming your data to a Pandas Dataframe with columns of `key`, `a`, `b`, and `c`. Then, dumping to CSV should be fairly painless.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of what your dictionary looks like, and what you want the csv to look like

Comment: @JackManey: is there an easy way in Pandas to do that?

Comment: @Andreas probably. Indeed, there is probably an easy way to do it *without* `pandas`. If you could **give an example of the data you are working with then someone might be able to answer your question**

Comment: @Andreas Yes. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html Just transform your data into the requisite DataFrame.

Comment: @Andreas: Dictionaries do not have methods such as `get_a`, `get_reference_key`, etc.

Comment: @JackManey: Thanks for pointing this out - the segments I am referring to are actually objects that do have the relevant methods attached to them. However, it is not very clear in my post

Comment: Okay, so what kind of output do you want? For this to make sense as a DataFrame, we could do `key_type` (values of 1 or 2), `metric`, `period_0`, and `period_1` as columns.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I just provided an example of how my dictionary is structured and the preferred output CSV structure. I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @Andreas you seem to have provided a screenshot of some sort of spreadsheet program, which leaves some ambiguities regarding what the actual csv would look like...

Comment: Yes, "CSV file" and "Excel file" are two very--*VERY*--different types of things (although Excel can read the former, albeit poorly).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: sorry for the ambiguities. I posted the relevant CSV structure

Comment: @Andreas: `0` and `1` are *horrible* names for columns.

Comment: @JackManey: Thanks - in time I will update the periods to actual dates in the output files. Why is it that 0 and 1 are horrible?

Comment: "`segments = [<object1>, <object2>]`" Ummm......how is this useful or pertinent to the question at hand?

Comment: @Andreas: Take a moment and think about why it might be bad to use an integer to represent both a column name and a possible indexed position of a row or column (even if the former is technically used as a string representation of an integer). Seriously. Take five minutes and think about it. I'll be right here.

Comment: @JackManey: Thanks for pointing out the problems with my question. I updated it accordingly.

Comment: Okay, so let's call the columns of the DataFrame that you want `key`, `metric`, `period_0`, and `period_1`. Try forming the rows. Specifically, what can you do to the dict `"key1": {0: {"a": 0.9, "b": 0.2, "c": 0.5}, 1:{"a": 0.91, "b": 0.3, "c": 0.4}}` to get the list `["key1", "a", 0.9, 0.91]`?

Comment: You shouldn't be posting screenshots of things easily reproducible as text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use the `csv` module for this, I don't think it's worth wrangling your data to get it to play nicely with the `pandas` DataFrame constructors. Note, I am writing the csv to a string i/o buffer instead of a file so I can print the results easily, but you can simply omit that stuff and just work with a normal file object.

```
>>> periods = [0, 1]
>>> metrics = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> import csv
>>> import io
```

Now, just build up your rows carefully:

```
>>> with io.StringIO() as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f)
...     writer.writerow(['Key','Metric', 0, 1])
...     for key in output_dict:
...         for metric in metrics:
...             row = [key, metric]
...             for p in periods:
...                 row.append(output_dict[key][p][metric])
...             writer.writerow(row)
...     final = f.getvalue()
...
16
17
18
18
17
16
16
>>> print(final)
Key,Metric,0,1
key2,a,0.4,0.21
key2,b,0.33,0.73
key2,c,0.34,0.54
key1,a,0.9,0.91
key1,b,0.2,0.3
key1,c,0.5,0.4
```

Note, the keys will not be in any particular order because dictionaries are unordered. You can impose an order by iterating over all keys if you know them ahead of time, like I did with the metrics and periods (your question implied those *were* known ahead of time). This solution can be extended to deal with missing keys pretty easily.

**EDIT**:
Your last edit seems to imply that you *will* know the keys ahead of time, so just do something like:

```
>>> periods = [0, 1]
>>> keys = ['key1', 'key2']
>>> metrics = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> with io.StringIO() as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f)
...     writer.writerow(['Key','Metric', 0, 1])
...     for key in keys:
...         for metric in metrics:
...             row = [key, metric]
...             for p in periods:
...                 row.append(output_dict[key][p][metric])
...             writer.writerow(row)
...     final = f.getvalue()
...
16
17
16
16
17
18
18
>>> print(final)
Key,Metric,0,1
key1,a,0.9,0.91
key1,b,0.2,0.3
key1,c,0.5,0.4
key2,a,0.4,0.21
key2,b,0.33,0.73
key2,c,0.34,0.54
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for!
Two questions regarding your posts:
a) how do you write the `final` to the csv file?
b) is there an easy way to make the "writerow" function dynamic (e.g. have unlimited periods)